# Regex to validate Credit Card numbers

Tags: validation, regular-expressions, validation-rule

I have created a validation rule on a Log Text field, to check for Credit Card number for all major companies "(VISA, Master Card, Discover and Amex for now).

Here is the validation rule:

```
 NOT( REGEX( Customfield__c ,
"^(4\\d{3}([\\s\\-]?)\\d{4}\\1\\d{4}\\1\\d{4})|(5[1-5]\\d{2}([\\s\\-]?)\\d{4}\\1\\d{4}\\1\\d{4}|(6(?:011|22(?:1(?=[\\s\\-]?(?:2[6-9]|[3-9]))|[2-8]|9(?=[\\s\\-]?(?:[01]|2[0-5])))|4[4-9]\\d|5\\d\\d)([\\s\\-]?)\\d{4}\\1\\d{4}\\1\\d{4})|(3[47]\\d\\d([\\s\\-]?)\\d{6}\\1\\d{5})$"))
```

**Problem**: Its only validating the initial regex pattern for Visa card's i.e. (4\d{3}([\s\-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}) and not the rest of patterns. I reckon it has to do with the validation rule vis-a-vis the regex. Any help on validation rule structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mubeen, this site is specific to technologies related to salesforce. This appears to be a pure regex question which isn't specific to salesforce. You can post this on stackoverflow which has a lot more people who can help on regex questions or any other code questions not specifically related to salesforce.

Comment: May be I haven't phrased my question correctly. But I was looking for validation rule help (and not regex help). Mark below has provided the information i was looking for and it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really more of a regex question than a SFDC question, so it truly belongs elsewhere in StackExchange.

However, if you know that your patterns work independently, you could change the definition of the VR to use an `OR()` statement instead of putting the conditionals within the regex pattern itself. This also greatly simplifies troubleshooting.

```
NOT( 
    OR(
        REGEX( Customfield__c , "Visa Pattern"),
        REGEX( Customfield__c , "Mastercard Pattern"),
        REGEX( Customfield__c , "Discover Pattern"),
        REGEX( Customfield__c , "AmEx Pattern")
    )
)
```